# Ionic capacitor live reload not working on android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I am using the following command to perform live reloading on android

```
ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external
```

But it is not working.

Here is the error I am getting

> ```
> The web page at http://localhost:8100/ could not be loaded because
>
> net : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> ```

I know that mobile devices don't understand localhost but I thought `--external` flag will take care of it.
Now what I have to do to get live reloading working on android.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in the tag (Tag application already exists):

- *`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">` may be needed just for API level > 28.*

3. Run live reload with the host of your PC.

```
ionic capacitor run android -l --host=127.0.0.1
```

*INSTEAD OF `127.0.0.1` YOU PUT YOUR PC'S IP ADDRESS.*

4. After run Android Studio with a connected device as usual.

Comment: The `--address` option is deprecated in favor of `--host`

Answer (score 3):

en my case i put this in capacitor.config.json

```
 {
"appId": "io.ionic.starter",
"appName": "medClinicApp",
"webDir": "www",
"bundledWebRuntime": false,
"cordova": {},
"server": {
  "url": "http://192.168.1.6:8100",
  "cleartext": true
 }
}
```

then run this command
`ionic cap run android -l --external`
and the most important is that **I disable my firewall.**

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, however, it has some different issues.

Live reload works on one tablet using android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  Android 5, but not on my new Samsung running Android 10. So apparently cleartext=true doesn't work in all cases. I know it's not Android studio or my laptop setup, since it serves to one device.

On the Samsung (Android 10) I can run the app itself, without live reload localhost, but when trying to put in debug mode it fails. I can also run the app in the browser of the Samsung using http://localhost:4200

I have been looking through a lot of threads, I thought I'd add it in here in case I find a solution or someone else has an idea for an alternative answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I tried everything but at the end it was the McAfee Firewall was enabled by my company IT on every laptop! disabling that solved this issue!
(I found out when I build an app with latest ionic/Capacitor) and saw that same issue happening.

PS: I was using Android Emulator (not a real device)